# I tried coding for inserting candidate using custom controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, null-pointer

```java
public class InsertCandidatecontroller {
    public Candidate__c can {get; set;}
    public InsertCandidatecontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }
    // Initialization of Candidate object
    public InsertCandidatecontroller()
    {
        if(can !=null)
        {
           can = new Candidate__c();
        }
        insert can;
    }
    public PageReference addnewCandidate()
    {
        PageReference RenderTo = new PageReference('/apex/Viewcandidate');
        RenderTo.setRedirect(false);
        return RenderTo;
    }
}
```

Am getting error.

> Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '{!addnewCandidate}' in component apex:commandButton in page newcandidate: Class.InsertCandidatecontroller.addnewCandidate: line 12, column 1

Someone Please solve this error. I stucked here.

Comment: Make sure your custom page is using your controller via `controller="InsertCandidatecontroller"` in the page tag at the top of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect logic here:

```java
    public InsertCandidatecontroller()
    {
        if(can !=null)
        {
           can = new Candidate__c();
        }
        insert can;
    }
```

Shouldn't you instantiate a new Candidate__c object when it is null?

```java
        if(can == null)
        {
           can = new Candidate__c();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ilawan. I changed this code using standard controller It's working. Still thanks for your time.